# content go under page footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I have an issue with my webpage. The issue is that the content go under the footer.

See my issue here
http://www.webdevout.net/test?0138

The container is

```
height:100%
```

`position:relative`
 while the footer is `absolute` and `bottom:0;`
I thought footer was made this way, what am I missing? I need the footer to have 50px(may be) distance from the content always.

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed. To avoid it, you should create a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and paste the code in the question. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I think the issue is related to the page in whole not just a small sample with 3 divs.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need absolute position in that case, because you just want to follow the correct page flow ; absolute position doesn't take other elements in account, so it is logical that your footer is hover your content.

Simply remove absolute position and add some margins. ;)

Comment: Add some margins? Will that really help if the page size differs from page to page?

Comment: Yep, because with relative position your footer will just go under the previous div, respecting the page flow.
Learn a bit more about how div are rendered in HTML page, 'cause you seem to misunderstood a lot of concepts. ;)
For example : http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the position absolute from the footer you'll be fine, then place a margin-top of 50px;

```
div.footer {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I need the footer to stick to the bottom. The page size differs.

Comment: This will help you :) http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I actually tried that. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the .footer has position absolute, it wont "push" the html-content further down.
If you add 
    padding-bottom: 40px;
to 
    div.main{

It will look allright.

This makes .main bigger

```
div.main {
width:800px;
min-height:400px;
margin-top:40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
padding-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking with Firebug, I found that removing "position:absolute" from div.footer class in your CSS, solves the problem.

Comment: It does not if the page size is smaller.

Comment: What do you see now? The footer is not pushed to the bottom of the page? Perhaps the answer above about margins clarifies this?